# Data structure recommendations

Tags: performance, data-structures, hash, hashtable

I am trying to make a data structure in which a single contact can be stored as “First Name”, “Last Name” and “phone number” in alphabetical order. With the passage of time phone book updates as new contact comes or removed from the phone book.
Following are two factors which must keep in mind while performing the required task.

- The available space is limited.
- Time required for accessing a particular contact must not exceed a given threshold.

If I use hash table, inspite of being fast enough, it would take a lot of space.
So what data structure should I use if there is space limitation of 2 GB?

Comment: the 2GB is a hard limit that no data structure can overcome. and what do you mean by if u were to use hash table then u will face thresh hold problem?

Comment: why its hard many smart phone have 2 gb memory limitation, and for thresh hold read the 2nd bullet point

Comment: Assuming that you have 4 GB worth of data needs to be loaded, how is your 2GB worth of memory gonna help? it is not solvable using any data structure. As for accessing elements in alphabetical order, you may wanna consider using Balanced Binary Search Trees(C++:Map, Java:TreeMap)

Comment: Completely agree with @Mox.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, if there is a hard limit of 2 GB, it essentially means that a data structure of constant space complexity is required.
Unfortunately, no such data structure exists.

On the other hand, a [Self-balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) is a very good data structure in terms of the tradeoff between time and space complexity.

Check out this [link](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) for the time and space complexities of various other data structures.